# How to enable appropriate driver for i2c device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

I am currently learning about linux device drivers, specifically for using an i2c device with a beaglebone. I have [this LCD](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B076L2CW3S/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) with a [PCF8574AT](https://www.nxp.com/part/PCF8574AT) on it. Searching through the linux drivers folders, I see that a driver [gpio-pcf857x.c](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux/drivers/gpio/gpio-pcf857x.c) already exists.

My question is how do I associate this device with this driver? When I do `ls -l /dev` the major number for i2c-2 is 89 which is the i2c character driver. How do I change this driver association? What material should I research on this? Also, I can see the slave address when I do `i2cdetect` so I know it is connected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The solution is here for how to instantiate i2c devices in linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices)